# Need to Get N number of records using random function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working one rails project,

i had a requirement like,

I have a User model which is having 1000 records. i need to get 3 records randomly out of thousand at a time.

if i use rand() function it will be applicable to getting to only one record    at a time.

can anybody tell me how to write the rand() function for getting N number of records

Answer (score 0):

Use it. i think this is helpful for you

```
@users = User.order('RAND()').limit(3)
```